# Celluloid::DeadActorError: attempted to call a dead actor when running app in vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, sidetiq

In my rails app I use the following gems:

```
gem "sidekiq-pro", "~> 2.1.3"
gem 'sidetiq', "~> 0.6.3", github: 'akhiln/sidetiq'
```

When I run my app using vagrant VM it returns the following error:

```
2016-01-03T00:20:02.214Z 15814 TID-ouw1nsoe4 ERROR: Actor crashed!
Celluloid::DeadActorError: attempted to call a dead actor
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/proxy/sync.rb:25:in `method_missing'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/set.rb:308:in `delete'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/set.rb:308:in `delete'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-pool-0.20.5/lib/celluloid/supervision/container/pool.rb:163:in `__crash_handler__'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:15:in `block in call'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:76:in `block in task'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:339:in `block in task'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/task.rb:44:in `block in initialize'
    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/task/fibered.rb:14:in `block in create'
2016-01-03T00:20:02.214Z 15814 TID-ouw1nsoe4 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 70127320173720 shutting down …
```

When I normally launch server it works correctly. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: sidetiq is a dead project, the author no longer supports it, you'd be advised not to use it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was helpful

[“ERROR — : Actor crashed! Celluloid::DeadActorError: attempted to call a dead actor”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596767/error-actor-crashed-celluloiddeadactorerror-attempted-to-call-a-dead-a/32145261#32145261)

[Celluloid::DeadActorError raised on shutdown](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1690)